# Deleting account with all content

Tags: support, accounts, licensing

Please delete my account including all posts (questions and answers) that I created.

When I search for the instructions to delete it, it says:

> User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes
>   will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.

I don't want my content to be made anonymous. All posts should be deleted because they are my content. I'll have to talk to my lawyer if that is not possible.

I tried to remove my posts but it doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: Your laywer will have to read the TOS that you agreed to when you created an account on SO and explain to you that your posts are licensed for use by others.

Comment: By all means follow the instructions for account deletion, but you have no right to demand that SO ceases to publish that content under a license you agreed to (your lawyer will happily bill you to agree with me, though).

Comment: It is not possible, talk to your lawyer.  They are a lot more smooth about it than meta visitors.

Comment: If you can own one's content and have the right to publish; it means you are the responsible for one's any kind of pornographic or illegal content. If you're not, then one can/should delete their own content. Do you think people are that stupid?

Comment: I try to think they're not, but I'm so frequently disappointed.

Comment: @BerdiyaOnur That kind of content would be wildly off-topic anyway, and thus quickly be deleted by the community. But - why do you want to delete all your content? Just to spite SE, or is there a more practical reason? Maybe we can work something out.

Comment: Same here, that's why I ask for my contents to be deleted. Holding the contents of that 'stupid' person and getting CLICKS from them is not ethical, is it? @TZHX

Comment: @BerdiyaOnur When users post content on SE they give everyone in the world the *right* to publish that content.  They don't give *anyone* an *obligation* to publish that content, so you aren't forcing SE to host illegal content if you do in fact post illegal content here.  SE can choose to delete it and refuse to host it, if *they* want to.

Comment: You put the content there, and in doing so agreed that it would be used the way it is being used. I think it's a big stretch to say that anything going on is not ethical; and it's ridiculously incorrect to suggest it's in any way legally actionable.

Comment: @BerdiyaOnur You've been here for several years, and have apparently made some useful and valued contributions. Sure, it's annoying if people whom you dislike, profit from your work. But that's the way of the world - if a construction worker builds a house, it may end up housing his mortal enemy. But good people will _also_ profit from your contributions.

Comment: @S.L. Barth: That's deep bro

Comment: There's hardly a more pathetic type of (l)user than this: ask loads of questions, benefit from the community, then try to delete all their questions - and all the answerers'  work with it. Thank goodness the CC license takes care of this. Good luck with "your lawyer."

Comment: Probably no point continuing to yell at them though, they can't answer for another 20 or so days and if the account gets nuked not at all.

Comment: I genuinely don't understand what it is about some people that, when they leave a site, they feel the need to *attack* the site in some way. That it's not enough to simply exit with dignity, to have a simple parting of the ways. That they have to make some grand gesture to harm the site before they go.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see some similarity when two people are going to divorce: They are so bitterly disappointed that the love didn't hold... *Give me my 50% of the cat ...*

Comment: Hopefully this doesn't come as a shock to anyone, but the internet is written in ink, not pencil. This is as childish as it is unproductive. I suspect that the community will guarantee that your content remains permanently on a matter of principle.

edit: I just took a look at his questions... what's the big deal? Your questions and answers have been generally well received...

Comment: Having seen some of the SO questions I'm surprised. There was a general lack of effort in many of them.

Comment: Please, please PLEASE talk to your lawyer, record the conversation, and post it for our enjoyment.  I'm BEGGING you.

Comment: @Will *OP explaining his issue* -- *45 minutes of lawyer laughing, then* "I will bill the full hour for that" *and hang up*

Comment: Links for the [Terms of Service: Network Content](http://stackexchange.com/legal#2NetworkContent) and the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).

Comment: What is funny about somebody stating that they will look for their rights? It wasn't a threat or something else. I just told you that I was going to consult my lawyer to see what it is about and what I can do. I'm not a specialist on licences. Craps or roses, they are my ideas, codes, questions etc. right? Look at what you have written and what  S.L. Barth wrote. Can you see the difference? Who's being childish?  And @Will it is obvious that you are here to make fun of things or vote things down instead of helping people, your profile makes it clear.

Comment: So much herd behaviour here. Ok guys, Reign over here, you're the king here. But only here :) You cannot suspend my account or manipulate/hold my posts anywhere else. I (and many more people) have so much criticism. You won't be able to shut our mouths there like you do here.  See: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-hate-Stack-Overflow

Comment: @Pekka웃 if you're talking about ungratefulness, and if that's a rivalry of who got the most benefit. you should have taken account of how many times my posts/answers are clicked and helped the others, including my answers. Maybe thousands of times! And some cocky infants can call that user with so much contribution 'stupid, silly etc'. And those who take the 'lawyer' example as a threat does NOT do anything to the ones that insulted. So it's like you got each others' back and try to make the user feel ashamed instead of trying to keep things in order.

Comment: `And some cocky infants can call that user with so much contribution 'stupid, silly etc'.` yes, it happens occasionally, to all of us. We don't all go into meltdown over it, and try to destroy the content we've contributed to the site.

Comment: That boils down to the personality and preference. I got no right to interfere with what your expectations are. Therefore I want no intervention in mine either. And moderators never tolerate the insults to them, they ban or suspend. So why expect newbies to swallow or overlook the insults? I wanted to leave with everything I did and told I was going to ask for legal help. Lawyer laughing, teasing, humiliation are all over there. When I attempted to go over it, they suspeded my account. I realized SO Meta don't accept criticism; anyway; we got many sites to do that.

Answer (score 24):

When you posted the content to SO you irrevocably licenced the content under the Creative Commons Wiki licence, giving everyone in the world the right to publish the content, or created derived works from it, so long as you are cited for it.  The site may choose to delete your content if it feels that it's not valuable to *us* to host it, but you do not have the right to demand it be taken down.  You only have the right to have your name no longer associated with that content.

Comment: Okay then I won't be bothered by editing every post of mine as 'content removed' 5 times and again and again.

Comment: @BerdiyaOnur there's no point doing that, it will just get rolled back, and your account will be suspended until deleted.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Too late, he tried it and is suspended.

Comment: @RobertLongson I am Jack's complete lack of surprise

Comment: I can't find the delete account link under the Edit Profile & Settings > Edit Profile as shown in here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account. Is it updated or made invisible for me?

Comment: @oferdofer: please read the *whole page* you linked to. That section only applies to accounts that have never posted anything. Further down that page is the section for accounts that have posted content: *Visit the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and select 'I need to delete my user profile.'*

Comment: @oferdofer read the TOS.