# Why this account page return 404 error?

Tags: support

Today I read a [post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/03/17/stack-overflow-culture/) about Jon Skeet's coding blog. It is about [this tweet](https://twitter.com/robconery/status/974678531832610816) from his friend Rob Conery. The tweet is about why he’s giving up contributing on Stack Overflow.

Then I wanted to check his account.

Account Link : https://stackoverflow.com/users/1151/rob-conery

But it returns 404. According [Deleting account with all content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328000/deleting-account-with-all-content), users can't delete account them self.

So how this account page return 404 error? What happened to his valuable past answers?

Comment: Rob Conery's posts are now for user "user1151". [Sample post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272026/some-issues-about-rob-conerys-repository-pattern/2336514#2336514). This is not searchable using Stack Exchange's interface, but the information is in the Stack Exchange dump, using the correct user ID, probably 1151.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An account can be deleted at user's request. This process is described in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account).

The answers remain. You can get  all of them with [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/526610/get-all-answers-by-a-deleted-user-together-with-questions?Name=user1151). Another approach is searching the site with Google for "user1151" (the string under this user's answers), but this does not work yet because it will take a while for the Google bot to re-crawl all those posts.

Comment: Thanks. If user want to get account back, is it possible?

Comment: The account is really deleted. As in, gone forever. They can create another one if they wish.